# How do I install the ClamAV extension for PHP 5?

Tags: php, clamav

I'd like to automatically scan uploaded files for viruses with php. There was an extension called php-clamavlib in earlier versions of ubuntu, but on Natty I get

> E: Unable to locate package php5-clamavlib

Isn't there any extension anymore? What could I do to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please download the latest `php-clamav` tarball from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/php-clamav).
- Install `php5-dev`, `clamav` if you haven't already with `sudo apt-get`
- Extract the tarball, `cd` into the *php-clamav-xxxx* directory, and follow these steps to install the *php-clamav* module (adapted from `INSTALL`):

  ```
  phpize
  ./configure --with-clamav
  make  
  cp modules/clamav.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/
  (restart Apache)
  service httpd restart
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I could install it without errors, but by downloading clamav (http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/sources/) + configure + make + make install. Guess apt-get install clamav doesn't install a version thats up-to-date enough. I couldn't get the extension work yet but that's maybe another question.

Comment: I had to uninstall the Ubuntu version of ClamAV then install the downloaded version linked above, followed by `php-clamav`. Is there a reason this has been dropped from Aptitude?

Comment: The extension folder above was wrong as well - you can find where the extensions are on your system by running `php-config --extension-dir`.

Comment: I also had to add a file to `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` with the contents: `extension=clamav.so` to enable the extension.

Answer (score 4):

Between izx's answer, 32bitfloat's comment and a bit of googling, I got this working (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). Here's exactly what I had to do. All these commands are as root, and some details may be different on your setup.

### Preparation

First, clear out any traces of existing ClamAV:

```
aptitude install zlib1g-dev php5-dev
aptitude purge clamav clamav-base clamav-data clamav-docs clamav-freshclam libclamav6
```

### Install ClamAV

[Download the latest ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/sources/), make and install it:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/clamav/clamav-0.98.4.tar.gz
tar xzf clamav-0.98.4.tar.gz
cd clamav-0.98.4
./configure
make
make install
ldconfig
```

Make freshclam work and run it:

```
useradd clamav
mkdir /usr/local/share/clamav
chown clamav /usr/local/share/clamav
cp /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf.sample /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

Edit the file `/usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf` and comment out the line that says `Example`. Then update:

```
freshclam
```

If that ran successfully, test it works by scanning a file:

```
clamscan somefile
```

### Install PHP-ClamAV

[Download the latest PHP-ClamAV](https://launchpad.net/php-clamav), make and install it:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/php-clamav/trunk/0.15.7/+download/php-clamav_0.15.7.tar.gz
tar xzf php-clamav_0.15.7.tar.gz
cd php-clamav_0.15.7
phpize
./configure --with-clamav
make
make install
```

Install into Apache and restart:

```
echo "extension=clamav.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/clamav.ini
service apache2 restart
```

I hope that lot's useful to somebody. I really wish `php-clamav` was still supported on Aptitude. It would be far nicer than the above.

Comment: By default the PHP extension reads virus DB from: `/var/lib/clamav`, which is default for `apt` clamav package, but in your answer the DB is: `/usr/local/share/clamav`.
Make sure you delete the data under: `/var/lib/clamav` (apt purge doesn't do it) and either make a link: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/clamav /var/lib/clamav` or modify the PHP clamav.ini adding: `clamav.dbpath=/usr/local/share/clamav`.

Comment: If you don't delete data `/var/lib/clamav`, you will end up with old virus data used by your PHP !
If you do delete data, but won't configure the link or new path, you should get: `LibClamAV Error: cl_load(): No such file or directory: /var/lib/clamav` when running `php -i`